# Why did James Bond draw his gun?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, casino-royale

In [*Casino Royale*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381061/) there is a scene during the poker game when *Bond* and *Vesper* go to their room during a pause. On their way *Bond* fetches an envelope from the reception (that I guess he deposited there earlier) containing his gun and then in the elevator **asks *Vesper* to open it and take out the gun**. When exiting the elevator they hear screams from *Le Chiffre*'s room (who is visited by his angry African clients) and *Bond* engages the danger.

But my question is, why did *Bond* take out the gun from the envelope in the first place, since at this point he didn't know there is danger ahead? He could have just done it in his room or not fetch/deposit the envelope at all.

- Am I just overinterpreting this and he just took it out as a matter of security?
- Was he actually anticipating the upcoming danger or knew that *Le Chiffre* got unwelcome visitors?
- Did he actually plan something serious I have overseen, like capturing *Le Chiffre* or at least searching his room or something the like?
- Or was this plot device of fetching the envelope and drawing out the gun just not thought out that well?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**You must have overlooked how Bond put a *tracker/microphone* on Le Chiffre's inhaler:**

[image: inhaler]

In the elevator he asks Vesper to open the envelope while he puts a wireless earpiece in his ear:

[image: earphone]

He takes the gun while holding a phone in his left hand:

[image: Phone]

The phone displays Le Chiffre's position:

[image: Phone]

So yes, Bond had a plan.

Comment: Hah indeed, totally forgot that, so it's clear he's up to something. The question seems pretty stupid now ;). The better question would be what he did plan (maybe he assumed that there was something strange going on and wanted to know what, since *Le Chiffre* talked to his henchmen right after the poker game). But well, that's just my bad of not thinking through it properly and asking too general a question (which you answered perfectly correct). Sorry, but well, at least you got some easy rep ;)

Comment: Epic!! That explianed a lot. I'm glad I read it!!

Comment: This answer is insufficient. They knew where LeChiffre would be (the casino) if it was just about killing him they could have staked out the place. The whole point of the CIA and MI6's plan was that they must beat Le Chiffre at cards to have enough leverage to bring him in. SomeSo it makes no sense why he was going to the room with the gun.

Comment: @user39984 Yes, and for that they need LeChiffre alive till the game is actually finished - meaning he has to survive this break - meaning Bond has to ensure that happens... and a gun might be really helpful with that...

Answer (score 0):

Throughout much of the movie, while bond was confident he could win, as he started losing chips, it became apparent that defeating him financially was no longer a strategy he could employ. So.....better off killing him. Another strategy having the gun for at least defending himself quietly should LeChiffre send assassins after him